# Need some guidance on function type definition

Tags: haskell, types, yesod

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my Yesod project (built out from the scaffolding).

```
No instance for (PersistBackend (GGHandler Scheduler Scheduler) IO)
  arising from a use of `checkDateStatus'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (PersistBackend (GGHandler Scheduler Scheduler) IO)
In the first argument of `checkM', namely `checkDateStatus'
In the expression: checkM checkDateStatus
In the expression:
    checkM checkDateStatus
  $ (jqueryDayField
       (def {jdsChangeYear = True, jdsYearRange = "2011:2012"}))
```

I believe this is because Haskell's type inference is failing. If this is the case, all I need to do is to give an accurate definition for checkDateStatus. If not a push in the right direction would be welcome. If I'm right, I'm still stuck as to what the type definition of checkDateStatus should be. I've been getting away with depending on type inference. Included below is the code I think is relevant. If I am missing something, please inform.

```
getManagerR :: Handler RepHtml
getManagerR = do
    ((res, widget), enctype) <- runFormGet productForm
    let findTestId = 1
        res' = prepST res
        scheduledTest = makeScheduledTest res'
    dataInsert <- runDB $ insert scheduledTest
    defaultLayout [whamlet|
<p>Result:#{show res}
   <form enctype=#{enctype}>
      ^{widget}
|]



productForm :: Html
            -> Form Scheduler Scheduler (FormResult SelectedProduct, Widget)
productForm extra = do
   pInfo <- liftIO getUIdata
   let products = V.toList $ V.map productACC  $ fst pInfo
       versions = V.toList $ V.map versionsACC $ snd pInfo
   (productRes, productView) <- mreq (radioField products) "Placeholder" Nothing
   versionInfo <- mapM generateVersionSelectFields versions
   (dateRes, dateView) <- mreq requestedDayField "Schedule" Nothing

--     (dateRes, dateView) <- mreq (jqueryDayField def
--                           { jdsChangeYear = True
--                           , jdsYearRange = "2011:2012"
--                           }) "Schedule" Nothing

   let versionRes = map fst versionInfo
       versionViews = map snd versionInfo
       widget = do
          toWidget [whamlet|
  #{extra}
 <p>
    ^{fvInput productView}
     $forall versionView <- versionViews
        ^{fvInput versionView}
    ^{fvInput dateView}
    <input type=submit value="Request Test">
 |]

   return (makeSelected productRes versionRes dateRes, widget)


requestedDayField = checkM checkDateStatus $ (jqueryDayField def
                                                     { jdsChangeYear = True
                                                     , jdsYearRange = "2011:2012"
                                                     })

errorMessage :: Text 
errorMessage = "I can't go for that, no can do."

checkDateStatus date = do
   maybeTaken <- getBy $ UniqueStartDate date
   case maybeTaken of
      Nothing -> return $ Left errorMessage
      otherwise -> return $ Right date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a runDB in front of the getBy.